# SyndicationClient await error in console app

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application

This sample application is a Windows 8 application that performs RSS aggregation.  I want to have my version of the application be a console app instead.  I want to go through the feeds and update another location based in which feeds have new items.  I don't care about displaying them in this app.  I just want raw speed and

The following code runs fine when in a Windows app but when placed in a console app, the await call gives an error message.

```
    private async Task<FeedData> GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)
    {
        // using Windows.Web.Syndication;
        var client = new SyndicationClient();
        var feedUri = new Uri(feedUriString);

        try
        {
            var feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
```

The error message is:

> Error  CS4036  'IAsyncOperationWithProgressRetrievalProgress>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no >extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of >type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress' could >be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

I have tried to modify the < TargetPlatformVersion > to be 8.1 but didn't see a change in the error.  I am developing on Windows 8.1 and using VS2015.  I have used specific types (SyndicationClient, URI, SyndicationFeed) in place of var with no luck as well.  I read somewhere that making them dynamic might help.

Comment: are you missing a using directive for 'System'?

Comment: No it is in there - the code doesn't throw the error when it is part of a Windows app with the modern UI.  The application template I am using is under Classic Desktop which seems to be related to my issue.